# Using ObjectLoader to load JSON that contains a BufferGeometry with multiple materials doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a sphere, with multiple materials, like so:

```
const materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({});
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ visible: false});
]

const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(2,100,100);
geometry.addGroup(0, Infinity, 0);
geometry.addGroup(0, Infinity, 1);

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The scene, light, camera are also defined (but not included here since they are not an issue).

This all works when the page loads (initialization).

Later I'm exporting the entire scene with `scene.toJSON()`. Then, later, I might want to load that JSON back in and replace the entire scene. I'm doing this with:

```
const loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.parse(jsonObject, function(object) {

    // instance is an object containing a bunch of things,
    // including the current scene. 
    // So I replace the current scene with the new one from the JSON

    instance.scene = object;
}
```

At this point, the scene gets replaced correctly, but the object does not appear (and I know the JSON is formed correctly).

I've tried, instead to create the sphere with

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2,100,100);
```

If I do that, then when loading the JSON the object appears correctly.

I'd prefer to use `SphereBufferGeometry()` but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Here are two examples. In both you should see a blank sphere, but in #1 you do not:

1. With `SphereBufferGeometry`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgQmMq
2. With `SphereGeometry`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agBEbp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

- When using the built-in geometry generators, `three.js` assumes that you do not modify the geometry data. But you are actually doing this by adding groups. These data are lost during the serialization/deserialization process. So the idea is to create a new `BufferGeometry` object and copy over the buffer attributes and indices. You can then freely define new data or overwrite existing ones.
- Besides, `Infinity` is a bad choice since it can't be serialized. It's better to set the value representing the last vertex for non-indexed geometry or the last index for an indexed geometry. I've updated your codepen with both fixes.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMbQgv

`three.js R105`

Comment: Thanks. The method I was using to add the groups (and using Infinity) was from something I found elsewhere (there's not too much about using multiple materials with `BufferGeometry`).

Comment: I think it's okay as long as you don't need `toJSON()`.